# Angular 5 - ag-grid 18.0.1 - edge crash

Tags: node.js, angular, web, npm, ag-grid

I've been searching everywhere and was unable to find any information related to this- most likely because ag-grid update 18.x is new.

Anyhow: It appears that after updating ag-grid from 17.1.1 to 18.0.1, any page with the ag-grid on it ends up crashing EDGE and IE. Chrome works fine. (There have always been performance issues with EDGE and IE but now ag-grid fails to even load).

My current project is using: Angular 5 in VSCode, AG-GRID, etc. An error I was able to view in the console was `onGridResize` no longer exists; However I am not calling this event what-so-ever.

So this appears to be something that has fallen off internally? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly ag-grid v18+ seems to be really buggy and unstable. I have an enterprise license and we ran into numerous issues that broke us too. We've had to downgrade back to v17.1.1 until they fix them. I'd probably stay away from v18 releases until they get it together on that build.

Comment: Alright, I thought as much. Thanks for the advice!