# Ag-Grid IE11 / React / WebPack does not load properly

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11, ag-grid

I am getting this error when I try out a simple rendition of ag-grid. The error occurs only in IE11. FF/Chrome/Edge are OK.

```
Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference
```

Looks like it has something to do with how Webpack is bundling the scripts. Haven't been able to figure this one out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 2018-07-02**

The order of my vendor and app files was incorrect. When I fixed the order, the grid issue was resolved, but it caused other (more serious) issues in my app. Ended up upgrading my Node, NPM, Webpack to 4.0 and revamped my config. Looks like it is working now. Hope it stays that way.

Comment: are you using the latest version - `18.0.1`? I think there are some issues with it. [Angular 5 - ag-grid 18.0.1 - edge crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51046994/1417185)

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version.

Comment: Hi Hari, please remove the answer from your question and add it es own answer, you might expand the answer a little.

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked on this app in a while now, so I am not able to provide more information. If I revisit it, I will provide more info.