# Ag grid (v18.0.1) Filter/Sorting not working in Visual Studio (2017)

Tags: angular5, ag-grid

I have an angular application (Angular5) running in visual studio 2017. I used ag grid (v7.0.2) earlier but recently upgraded to v18.0.1 after which certain features such as column filter and sorting stopped working. I am able to set properties in grid options for my grid and values such as enableColResize, showToolPanel are working as expected but not enableFilter/enableSorting. I tried to enables these properties in columnDef as well on each column but in vain.

Having said that, I am able to forcefully sort columns (after grid is initialized) but once that's done its not allowing me to change sort order.

The order of creating this grid is initializing it first (providing gridoptions) and then providing data.

Any suggestion is more than welcome!!

Comment: try switching to `17.1.1` version, the latest version has some issues. you can go through recent questions posted on [tag:ag-grid]

Comment: **[Ques 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51073078/1417185)**, **[Ques 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51046994/1417185)**

Comment: Thanks for help Paritosh...i tried to change version to 17.1.1 but now the grid is not getting loaded....i have tried to create a stand alone application with angular 5, ag grid 18 in VS 2017 and its working as expected (sort,filter). I added this project in my current solution, it works fine. So i am guessing there is something with systemjs.config.....

Comment: Reproduce ur issue on stackblitz or plunk and share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was css overlapping issue. Though i have imported new ag-grid.css at a separate path but in final mark up, my app was referring old css as well which was causing filter/sort visibility issue.